# Change all selections on the page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, foreach

I want to change all selections on my page and set them to an index I define using javascript language.

Can you please advice on this ?

Comment: Did you try google?

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code snippet:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Pineapple</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
</select>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "2";
    }
</script>
```

"2" represents index for the select element.